# How can I get the columns in tkinter to set their size based on the smallest widget in the column and not the widget spanning both columns?

Tags: python, tkinter, grid, columnspan

I'm working with tkinter in Python and using grid, and when I put two widgets in different columns in one row and a widget spanning both columns in another row, then the columns' widths are both set to half the width of the widget spanning both rows. Is there any way I could get it to fit the columns to the two widgets?

The reason I want this is to get the left widget to fill all of the width of the spanning widget except for that taken up by the right widget, which should be a fixed width.

The code is like this:

```
spanningboth.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan = 2)
infirstcol.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky='EW')
insecondcol.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
```

Comment: _" If I do the same thing, but put the two widgets in a lower row, then the columns' widths are both set to half the width of the widget spanning both rows."_ - that is not a true statement. The behavior is identical whether the two smaller widgets are on top or below. Please provide a _complete_ [mcve] to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley I realized right after I posted the question that that part was incorrect, and edited the question.

Comment: You cannot do it because logically a row/column is reserved to that widget no matter how much space it takes, You can't really do anything about that except use a different geometry manager or set more columns

Comment: @Matiiss:  your comment doesn't make much sense. `grid` is highly configurable. Most likely the solution to the OP's problem can be done with `grid`.

Comment: Use `.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` on the parent of the widgets.

Comment: @acw1668 That does exactly what I want. Do you want to put that in an answer so I can mark it as correct?